# Reduce the cost of Including Multiple javascripts

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, http-get

I have developed an application using backbone.js So I have created multiple models and multiple views. Initially I created them in one file but after some further reading, I came to know it is advisable to keep models separate, views separate and all routers separate. I just want to know, if we do this We will be increasing the number of HTTP Get requests (one for each javascript file) So this practice leads to some extra cost.

Q. How can we reduce this cost ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at require.js

http://requirejs.org/

and this tutorial

http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/

Answer (score 0):

I just came across to this question surfing something else and found this my own question.
If I were to answer this now, it would be this:

Keep your Models, Views, Routers etc in separate files but always merge them and then include link of merged file in your HTML code.

You can use some `runtime JS minifier` just like mentioned in this blog [Minify JS runtime in PHP](http://verens.com/2008/05/20/efficient-js-minification-using-php/)

There are other online tools available too.